# How can I turn off the fast walking ability in the smart moving mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

So I was trying out the smart moving mod and I made my player run fast by pressing the O button a lot then I thought it was cool until I reached the limit on how fast it could Go and each time I'd want to move my whole Minecraft would jam! So I need help on how to make my player normal speed again someone.

What do I do I'm confused! and each time I press O again it says speed set to 2133457587% I'm trying to make it 100% I also checked the control options and saw a button that said decrease speed smart moving mod, and it was P and I pressed P and nothing happened!

Answer (score 1):

hey man i found it out by accident. its  the I key that slows the speed down